# Can I pick up possible calendar events from a text file

Tags: machine-learning, text-summarization

I am new to this community and not even too sure if this is the right place for such a question.

I want to know how I could implement (possibly with already made solutions) a system which could take in a (possibly long winded) text file and deduct from there, events and meetings which a user could add (similar to what Siri does when it finds a possible event).

Is there something for this that already exists?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine training a model of your own, I would suggest try building a NER prediction model on your data. It would help to start with a certain type of data which follows similar pattern throughout. Once you're confident, you can extend it to many more patterns.

Or if you're lucky and find [pre-trained NER models](https://huggingface.co/models?search=ner) to be able to identify the event-date relationships already, you can just use them out-of-the-box.

Interestingly, I tried some [QA models](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=question-answering&sort=downloads) to simply ask the event & time of event given some context, and [deepset/roberta-base-squad2](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2) works pretty well for simple examples.

> Context: I have a flight to catch at 6 AM tomorrow.
>
> Question: What is the topic of event?
> Answer: a flight to catch at 6 AM tomorrow
>
> What is the date of event?
> 6 AM tomorrow

> Context: The next set of features are scheduled to be discussed at meeting on 25th Dec 2022.
>
> Question: What is the topic of event?
> Answer: The next set of features
>
> Question: What is the date of event?
> Answer: 25th Dec 2022

Of course your data could be very different, but the pre-trained models should be a good starting point for ideas.